# Piano fingering for chromatic fifths, is a fifth too wide for fingering 2-4?

Tags: piano, fingering

I'm trying a fingering that basically limits white keys to fingers 1 & 5 and black keys to 2 & 4. This fingering seems good for non-legato for medium size intervals perfect fourths and augmented fourths. It seems to work for perfect fifths too, but I'm wondering if fingering 2-4 for two black keys it too wide a stretch?

[image]

May hand span is a bit more that 8.25 inches/21 cm, so a little little on the small side.

This 2-4 span doesn't feel uncomfortable after my hands warm up, but I think I will get fatigued from it fairly soon.

Is this fingering either strange or this 2-4 span pushing against a general limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For black keys, 2-4 doesn't stretch too far.  Compare it to the runs of parallel diminished fifths in the middle of Chopin's etude Op. 10 #3.  (I bet you'll tire  sooner from *hearing* that many parallel perfect fifths than from *playing* them.)

[image]

Comment: That's a good example. I will look at Debussy's Etudes as well. I know some of his were based on intervals.  BTW, I've been placing my hands apart by octave, 10th and 12th to get some variety of sounds, plain fifths, seventh chords, and quintal harmony. That helps alleviate the monotony.